# Speech recognition in a text area

Tags: jquery, html, webkit, google-chrome-extension, speech-recognition

I want to attach the webkit speech recognition plugin in a text area. What I currently  have:

```
<input type="text" x-webkit-speech />
```

That works. But if I type this:

```
<textarea cols="88" rows="6" x-webkit-speech />
```

It doesn't work. Is there any way to do that? Maybe with jQuery?

Comment: Hello from the future! `x-webkit-speech` was deprecated a few years after this was asked. More discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887521/speech-recognition-with-x-webkit-speech-does-not-work-in-chrome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.phpied.com/x-webkit-speech-input-and-textareas/) They've demonstrated how you can do it

Answer (score 0):

Currently `x-webkit-speech` only works with input.  There are some hacks that you can to so it appears that your textarea has `x-webkit-speech`.  Basically you would have a input text and take that input and fill in the text area.