# Speech recognition with x-webkit-speech does not work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, voice-recognition

I am trying voice recognition using x-webkit-speech,i have also checked it is supported in my chrome browser , but it is giving error connection to speech server failed.

Comment: x-webkit-speech tag has been deprecated. Use new Chrome speech API like here: http://shapeshed.com/html5-speech-recognition-api/

Answer (score 4):

> The x-webkit-speech input field attribute is deprecated. Please use the JavaScript API instead.

There is a JavaScript SpeechRecognition API that does text-to-speech and speech-to-text. Not many browsers support it but Chrome should have support.

For your reference Github project for this purpose: https://github.com/Daniel-Hug/speech-input